# Is there a way to make `man` reflow text when the terminal window is resized?

Tags: man, text-formatting

`man` apparently uses `less -s` as the default pager, which does reflow text when the terminal window is resized, but this does not happen in `man`.

Is there any way of making `man` reflow text, so that it uses all the space in a resized window which has been made wider? (preferably while still keeping the right margin justification)

Comment: @Paradroid, I've undeleted this post as it can be useful for future searches that use your key words instead of the target post.